# How to update a table, delete entries from the table asynchronously using jquery, ajax, php, and mysql?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, asynchronous

Okay, so I have a page that builds a table base on a mySQL table using php:

tables.php

```
$page .='<form method="POST" action="processing.php">';
$page .= "<table> \n";
$page .= "<tr>\n";  
$page .= "<th>ID</th> \n <th>First Name</th> \n <th>Last Name</th> \n <th>PhoneNumber</th> \n <th>Email</th> \n";

//Loops through each contact, displaying information in a table according to login status
$sql2="SELECT cID, firstName, lastName, phoneNum, email FROM Contact WHERE oID=".$_GET['orgID'];
$result2=mysql_query($sql2, $connection) or die($sql1);
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_object($result2))
{
    $page .= "<tr>\n";
    $page .= "<td>".$row2->cID."</td>\n";
    $page .= "<td>".$row2->firstName."</td>\n";
    $page .= "<td>".$row2->lastName."</td>\n";
    $page .= "<td>".$row2->phoneNum."</td>\n";
    $page .= "<td>".$row2->email."</td>\n";
    //Will only display these buttons if logged in
    $page .= '<td><input type="checkbox" name="checkedItem[]" value="'.$row2->cID.'"></input></td>'."\n";
    $page .= "<td>".makeLink("addEditContact.php?cID=".$row2->cID, "Edit")."</td>\n";
    $page .="</tr>";
}


$page .= "</table>";
//Two buttons sending to processing.php to decide what to do with selected values from there
$page .= '<input name="addToContacts" type="submit" value="Add Selected Contacts To Contact List" />'."\n" ;
$page .= '<input name="deleteContacts" type="submit" value="Delete Selected Contacts" />'."\n";
$page .= "</form>\n";
mysql_close($connection);
```

So base on the checkboxes, I can choose to add contacts to another table, or delete contacts off of this table by first sending the information of this form into a processing.php page that decides which button was click and redirects to the proper php script:

processing.php:

```
if(!empty($_POST['checkedItem']))
{
    //Because addToContacts and deleteContacts take in GET instead of POST for convinience, it needs to take all of checkItems and implode it
    $var=$_POST['checkedItem'];
    ksort($var);
    $joinedString= implode(',',$var);
    //Since there are two buttons in orgDetail, it checks for which was pushed and sends it to the correct page
    if(!empty($_POST['addToContacts']))
    {
        header('Location: addToContacts.php?cID='.$joinedString);
    }

    else if($_POST['deleteContacts'])
    {
        header('Location: deleteContacts.php?cID='.$joinedString);
    }
}
else
{
    //Error for not selecting any items
    $page .= makeP("You have not checked off any items. Please click ".makeLink( $currentPage, "here")." to return to previous page");
}
```

And since I am only interested in the delete contact case right now. Here is deleteContacts.php

```
$explodedString=explode(',',$_GET['cID']);


    foreach($explodedString as $eString)
    {
        $sql1="DELETE FROM Contact WHERE cID='".$eString."'";
        mysql_query($sql1, $connection) or die($sql1);
    }
header('Location: '. $currentPage);
```

So from here is where it gets complicated. This works fine when I want the page to work synchronously. It bounces around php scripts and all is well. What if I want to delete directly from tables.php using jquery. So what I mean is that, it will run the mysql query to delete the entries from the actual db, and as well after it does that update the table view in tables.php to reflect that change; all done asynchronously?

(Please ignore the fact that all the sql queries aren't escaped strings, I realize that and I'll have to fix that later)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you are reinventing the wheel. Take a look at the jquery dataTables. It is a powerfull plugin to manage table and do all you need. With this plugin, you just have to make the server side processing, all the UI part/client part is ready to use. http://www.datatables.net/

Comment: The problem is I have to also make it work in case JS is turned off. In which case I'm not sure if jquery dataTables will handle it.

Comment: You will not be able to refresh and doing ajax if JS is disabled..

Answer (score 0):

If you need to support the table without javascript then get this working first

Your only way to keep the table up to date without Javascript enabled is to refresh the page and redraw the table on each load.